# locals variable not updating correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I am displaying a bunch of pages from a collection, so to have them available in my view I initialize a global `locals` variable in `app.js` like so:

```
Page.find({}).sort({ sorting : 1}).exec(function(err, pages){
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        app.locals.pages = pages;
    }
});
```

That works fine. However, I also have the ability to reorder the way those pages show up, so after i do the reordering I redo the `Page.find()` from above in that same route, but it seems to always be one step behind.

So if I make a change by reordering (let's call it `reorder 1`), I do not see a difference in `app.locals.pages` after that, but if I reorder again (let's call this `reorder 2`, then I see the `reorder 1` ordering and not `reorder 2` and so on always, so basically it's always a step behind.

Relevant code from the route:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
        var id = ids[i];
        count++;
        (function(count) {
            Page.findById(id, function (err, page) {
                page.sorting = count;
                page.save(function (err) {
                    if (err)
                        console.log(err); 
                });
            });
        })(count);
    }

    Page.find({}).sort({sorting: 1}).exec(function (err, pages) { // this is always a step behind
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            req.app.locals.pages = pages;
        }
    });
```

Why isn't it getting the latest?

Comment: I didn't exactly understand your problem lol. What do you want to do ?

Comment: @boubaks After the for loop runs and values in the db change, req.app.locals.pages does not reflect the latest changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey, then I understood your problem.

The problem is than your `page.save` take more time than your `for`
So after your find will get almost the same result than before.

Where do you use it (`for`) ? in a special route ?

Simple Asynchronous javascript problems ;)

```

```
function sortPages(ids, callback) {
  var total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
    var id = ids[i];
    count++;
    (function(count) {
        Page.findById(id, function (err, page) {
            page.sorting = count;
            page.save(function (err) {
                ++total;
                if (err)
                    console.log(err);
                if (total >= ids.length) {
                  callback('done');
                }
            });
        });
    })(count);
  }
}

sortPages(ids, function () {
  Page.find({}).sort({sorting: 1}).exec(function (err, pages) {
      if (err) {
          console.log(err);
      } else {
          req.app.locals.pages = pages;
      }
  });
});
```

```

Comment: Yes, I had a problem with the foor loop as well before using the closure in the for loop, it wasn't updating properly. It is all in the same route, the for loop and then the page.save, any remedy for this?

Comment: You have to wrap the first back in a function which get a callback I will write you an example (you can also uses promises but more easier to understand with callback in first time)

Comment: I edited my message with the callback example @VojislavKovacevic
Also I didn't manage if Page.findById throw an error so you will have also to check that