# Node acting synchronously, waiting for the loop to finish

Tags: node.js

I have encounted a few issues in the project I am doing since node is async, but now I have a `for loop` and I do something after the loop ends or breaks, and it seems to be working synchronously and I want to know why.

I have this code:

```
            var newItem = true;

            for (var i = 0; i < cart.length; i++) {
                if (cart[i].title == slug) {
                    cart[i].qty++;

                    newItem = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (newItem) {
                cart.push({
                    title: slug
                });
        }
```

And all this works as expected! the `newItem` variable always has the correct value.

How come newitem is not always `true`?

I never have more than 3 items in the `cart` array, is this why? Would it behave differently if I had a 1000 items?

Comment: this code is synchronous that is why

Comment: Seems to but I don't think it should behave so. I had a for loop in another instance and updating the database inside the loop and also getting some results after the loop, and it didn't work synchronously, I had to create a function with a callback.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have provide is running synchronously, if you want to test whether it works in an asynchronous condition try running this code

```
var newItem = true;

for (var i = 0; i < cart.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        if (cart[i].title == slug) {
            cart[i].qty++;

            newItem = false;
            break;
        }
    }, 1000);
}

if (newItem) {
    cart.push({
        title: slug
    }
}
```

Comment: I had similar code where database was being updated inside of a loop and after the loop finished I got results from the db, but the results were always a step behind, and the code was similar to this. The code to get results from the db did not wait for the loop to finish, so I do not understand why `if (newItem)` here is waiting for the loop to finish.

Comment: How is the code here different form the code in the question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45484161/locals-variable-not-updating-correctly ?

Comment: well in this example the if would run after the for loop, but since it is making an async call the part inside the setTimeout would occur atleast after 1 second hence newItem would initially be false after the loop finished

Comment: Never mind the set timeout part, I am talking without it, as i have it in in my q. Why does the `if` here run after the loop and here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45484161/locals-variable-not-updating-correctly it doesnt ?

Comment: over their the solution used a callback to handle events which should occur after the loop has finished, so the callback is called after the for loop has finished executing so it would receive the latest updates

Comment: try reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10783093/any-better-way-to-combine-multiple-callbacks